# Creating multiple variables to view the frequency of them in time

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm currently working with a dataframe which has this structure:

| Date | Term | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-28 | politics | 42 |
| 2022-10-26 | biology | 69 |

It was generated to summarize the frequency of a certain word by date, from a larger database of social media posts.

Here's example data:

```
examp.data <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2013-09-23", "2014-11-15", "2014-05-11",
                         "2015-03-27")),
  term = c("engineering","biology","physics","mathematics","computer"),
  freq = c(732,917,241,601,692), 
 
 stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

The object is to produce a plot that looks this

[image]

from one that right now looks this:

[image]

I was assuming I could achieve this by creating new variables (columns) based on each word and then plotting them using the same x axis (dates). But I can't figure a way to transform the data to do it.

Comment: Can you post the data that makes the `dates+frequency` figure and the code you used to generate it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to transform the data.  You can just use ggplot aesthetics.

```r
dat %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(date, freq, color = term) + 
  geom_line()
```